# State is undefined, but ONLY in Test Flight

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have the following component with the following functions (alerts included to show where state is weird):

```
const CategoryArticlesChild = (props) => {
  const categories = useSelector((state) => state.settings.cats);
  const show_read = useSelector((state) => state.settings.show_read);
  const skills = useSelector((state) => state.settings.skill);
  const date = useSelector((state) => state.date);
  ...

  const loadArticlesByCategory = () => {
    const hsks = getLevels(skills);
    const limit = (categories.length + 1) * 15;
    let _query = {
      category: categories,
      limit: limit,
      ordering: "-date",
      published: 1,
      display_skill: hsks,
      taxon: props.taxon,
      show_read: show_read,
    };
    alert(JSON.stringify(_query));
    alert(JSON.stringify(date));
    _query = processDates(date, _query);
    if (!_.isEqual(query, _query)) {
      setQuery(_query);
    } else {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

 useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading) {
      setIsLoading(true);
    }
    if (
      categories &&
      skills &&
      !_.isUndefined(date) &&
      date &&
      show_read !== null
    ) {
      loadAllArticles();
    }
  }, [categories, date, skills, show_read]);


...
}
```

The **ONLY** place that loadArticlesByCategory is called is in the useEffect above.

And on web (I am using React Native Web), iOS simulator and Xcode build on device, it all works fine.

But then when I push to Test Flight, date is undefined. Even though, as you can see, I use a Lodash function to check DIRECTLY if it is undefined, and prevent execution of the function if it isn't defined.

What exactly am I missing here? Why is date constantly undefined, but ONLY in Test Flight, and despite me setting code that should explicitly stop it from being undefined

Comment: could the date be something else? null, empty string, etc

Comment: @Abe No it is absolutely undefined, the alert is saying undefined. I also have at various points checked whether it was falsey at all - no dice

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code to the following (and also added the arguments to the other function):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading) {
      setIsLoading(true);
    }
    if (
      categories &&
      skills &&
      !_.isUndefined(date) &&
      date &&
      show_read !== null
    ) {
      loadArticlesByCategory(categories, skills, date, show_read);
    }
  }, [categories, date, skills, show_read]);
```

Fixed this particular bug.

So my best guess is that this is some sort of React immutability issue or some sort of race condition?

Comment: Nice. It could be a stale closure no? The values that `loadAllFunctions` was getting were from an older scope perhaps